# New to jQuery: is something wrong with this code sample?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get some jQuery to run, I think it has something to do with my `.js` file. Here is the entire file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown")
    .on('change keyup', colorizeSelect)
    .change();
});

function colorizeSelect(){
    if($(this).val() == "") $(this).addClass("dropdown_placeholder");
    else $(this).removeClass("dropdown_placeholder")
}
```

I found this sample on this site, and although it doesn't make sense to me it supposedly should work. Does anyone see anything wrong with this? I am pretty sure my html is setup properly to work with this.

Comment: Do you get an error in the JS console

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of this line `else $(this).removeClass("dropdown_placeholder")`

Comment: @user1477388 Thanks I added the semicolon but am still having no luck.

Comment: @user1477388 that's not a problem.

Comment: Do you import jQuery ? Do you have the css classes and the .dropdown input defined ? Please give us your (minimal) HTML and if possible a fiddle.

Comment: @dystroy I cannot include the html unfortunately, I am mostly just interested in removing the .js file as a potential problem (i.e. can compile just fine, etc). Thanks.

Comment: if($(this).val() == "") $(this).addClass("dropdown_placeholder");
your code block is not wrapped in {} and the next line else $(this).removeClass("dropdown_placeholder") is missing a semi colon at the end.

Comment: @dystroy I imported the my script using `<script src="mypath/js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head. Do I need to do anything else to ensure this code is triggered properly?

Comment: Well, you need something like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` just before.

Comment: You have to include jQuery

Comment: Include jQuery, then inspect the page in firefox and make sure that you can find both jquery and this in the loaded scripts.

Comment: @dystroy My apologies, I already have that included (this is a team effort). Is there an easier script I could run just to see if it is even being called? This would help point the error to my html. Thanks.

Comment: Check if alert($("body").length()); does anything (It should return a number).

Comment: I had to replace $ with `jQuery` because it was saying $ is undefined. I also inspected the element in question and my js script is throwing the uncaught error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" on the lines `if(jQuery(this).val() == "") jQuery(this).addClass("dropdown_placeholder");` and `jQuery(".dropdown").on('change keyup', colorizeSelect()).change();`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: After even further inspection I found it is a problem with `$(this)`. Is this not a valid statement?

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem, use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").on('change keyup', colorizeSelect()).change();
});

function colorizeSelect(){
    if($(this).val() == "") $(this).addClass("dropdown_placeholder");
    else $(this).removeClass("dropdown_placeholder");
}
```

Comment: Seems like you remove the change event triggering. That's probably not what's desired.

Comment: I think that on("change") and change() are the same aren't they?

Comment: change without arguments triggers the event.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. I learned something new! Thanks, I'll update the code.